# Bigquery Date Issue

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery, datetime-format

I'm trying to parse out a date in google bigquery and running into this issue.
Column is SessionDateTime and is a string.

PARSE_DATE("%m%d%y", SessionDateTime) as parsed_column
Returns
Failed to parse input string "3/1/2022 03:06 PM"

Any suggestions? Is it the AM/PM causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Able to find the answer.

```
PARSE_DATETIME( '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p', SessionDateTime )
```